# $U_{n+1} = 2U_n^2 - 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to find the general term for the progression defined by :

$U_{n+1} = 2U_n^2 - 1$

Can any one help me out ? Is it even possible to find the general term ?

Comment: In general, recursive sequences defined by $U_{n+1}=aU_n^2+bU_n+c$ are [logistic maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map).

Comment: Any special value for $U_0$?

Comment: [A good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831): The title of a question is the first thing people see. Like headings in newspapers, book, song and album titles, their importance is not to be underestimated -- the presence of a good, descriptive title for your question often greatly improves the exposure (and hence the amount and quality of answers) it gets. To ensure maximal descriptiveness of your question's title, review it before posting and ensure that it (still) adequately describes your question's content. And be sure to include at least some plain words.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT:** Notice that 
$$2x^2-1=\cos(2\arccos(x))$$
for $x\in [-1,1]$, and
$$2x^2-1=\cosh(2\operatorname{arccosh}(x))$$
for $x\notin [-1,1]$.

Also observe that if $s(x)=2x^2-1$, then
$$U_{n+1}=s(U_n)$$

Comment: [+1] Indeed, $2x^2-1=T_2(x)$ the second Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Comment: @JeanMarie Ah, my beloved Chebyshev polynomials... how*ever* would I iterate quadratics without you? <3

Answer (score 2):

If $U_1 = (a + \frac{1}{a})/2$, then $U_n = (a^{2^n} + \frac{1}{a^{2^n}})/2$.